# Recibir respuesta, y mostrar Url recibida en React

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs

Tengo unos códigos Java y React construidos. El funcionamiento debería ser el siguiente: desde React llamo a la clase de Java que a su vez llama a la API de Ogone y recibe una respuesta JSON la cual meto en un objeto, esta respuesta pasa a React. Dentro de el objeto hay una variable llamada *hostedTokenizationUrl*, que es esta URL la cual debe mostrarse al recibir el objeto desde la clase de java. Pero no lo consigo.

Os dejo los códigos por aquí.

React:

```
const handleClick = async () => {
const url = 'http://localhost:8080/hostedTokenizationSession';
const options = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({}) // el cuerpo de la solicitud está vacíoq
};

const response = await fetch(url, options);
const data = await response.json();

setResponseData(data);

if (data.hostedTokenizationUrl) {
  setTokenizationUrl(data.hostedTokenizationUrl);
} else {
  console.log('No se ha recibido la URL de la sesión de tokenización');
}


<div className="App">
  <button onClick={handleClick}>
    Realizar llamada a hostedTokenizationSession
  </button>
  {tokenizationUrl && (
    <div>
      <p>La URL recibida es:</p>
      <p>{tokenizationUrl}</p>
    </div>
  )}
</div>
```

Java:

```
@PostMapping("/hostedTokenizationSession")
public HostedTokenizationSessionResponse hostedTokenizationSession() throws AuthenticationException, IOException, InterruptedException {

    //Crear un nuevo objeto HttpClient
    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newBuilder()
            .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_1_1)
            .build();

    HttpResponse<String> response = httpClient.send(getRequest(), HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());

    return OBJECT_MAPPER.readValue(response.body(), HostedTokenizationSessionResponse.class);
}
```